# Downloading all dependencies for Maven test

Tags: java, docker, maven, junit

I'm running tests in a Docker container that uses the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM maven:3.5.3-jdk-8
ENV APP_DIR=/app
RUN mkdir -p $APP_DIR
WORKDIR $APP_DIR
COPY pom.xml .
RUN mvn -B dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=test
COPY . $APP_DIR
RUN mvn -B test-compile compile
ENTRYPOINT ["mvn", "test"]
```

It does download some dependencies during build process. The problem is when `mvn test` is running in the Docker container, it downloads some dependencies related to the Surefire plugin. What Maven command could be used to download them during the build? The project is just a basic app created with a wizard with the following `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47969389/how-can-i-cache-maven-dependencies-and-plugins-in-a-docker-multi-stage-build-lay

Comment: I'm having the same issue and the "Related question" doesn't seem to solve it.

Comment: @PhilNinan : how did you guys solve it eventually?

Comment: I did not get this fully working. but you can create a docker image from a container. this would be a bit of a manual process to create the image, run commands so all dependencies are downloaded, and create another image from the container that now has all the dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple suggestion: Instead of doing

```
RUN mvn -B dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=test
```

you could simply do

```
RUN mvn -B test
```

Because no source or test files have been added to the container at this point, no actual test will be executed, but *most* of the required Surefire dependencies will be downloaded. Note: *most*, not all.

When I tested this with the mentioned JUnit 3 dependency, the number of downloaded dependencies during `mvn test` was reduced from 22 to 3:

```
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit3/2.12.4/surefire-junit3-2.12.4.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-providers/2.12.4/surefire-providers-2.12.4.pom
Downloaded from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/surefire/surefire-junit3/2.12.4/surefire-junit3-2.12.4.jar
```

This is not so bad, maybe.