# Mounting Volume as part of a multi-stage build

Tags: docker, docker-compose

How can I mount a volume to store my .m2 repo so I don't have to download the internet on every build?

My build is a Multi stage build:

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 as BUILD

COPY . /usr/src/app
RUN mvn --batch-mode -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean package

FROM openjdk:8-jdk
COPY --from=BUILD /usr/src/app/target /opt/target
WORKDIR /opt/target
    
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "find -type f -name '*.jar' | xargs java -jar"]
```

Comment: You cannot mount a volume as part of the build process.  Builds are meant to be independent from your host.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven docker cache dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208442/maven-docker-cache-dependencies)

Comment: You cannot access volume data during a build. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51627401/cant-access-a-volume-during-building-a-docker-image

Comment: @larsks There are things that might benefit from not being independent (package caches which you would otherwise have to pull over the Internet for each build, and for which a given version doesn't change).

Comment: I wish I could give your question a bounty just because of "download the internet". That's exactly how I feel! 

Answer (score 23):

You can do that with Docker >18.09 and BuildKit. You need to enable BuildKit:

```
export DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1
```

Then you need to enable experimental dockerfile frontend features, by adding as first line do Dockerfile:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:experimental
```

Afterwards you can call the RUN command [with cache mount](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md#build-mounts-run---mount). Cache mounts stay persistent during builds:

```
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 \
    mvn --batch-mode -f /usr/src/app/pom.xml clean package
```

Comment: Does this mount the .m2 from host machine into the docker build environment? When I tried to run the container, exec and see what is in the "target" path inside the container, I did not see the same contents as the host machine. It was empty and hence my "mvn -o install" would not work..

Answer (score 0):

Although the anwer from @Marek Obuchowicz is still valid, here is a small update.

First add this line to `Dockerfile`:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
```

You can set the `DOCKER_BUILDKIT` inline like this:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t mytag .
```

I would also suggest to split the dependency resolution and packagin phase, so you can take the full advantage from Docker layer caching (if nothing changes in `pom.xml` it will use the cached layer with already downloaded dependencies). The full `Dockerfile` could look like this:

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM maven:3.6.3-openjdk-17 AS MAVEN_BUILD
COPY ./pom.xml ./pom.xml
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 mvn dependency:go-offline -B
COPY ./src ./src
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.m2 mvn package

FROM openjdk:17-slim-buster
EXPOSE 8080
COPY --from=MAVEN_BUILD /target/myapp-*.jar /app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/app.jar","-Xms512M","-Xmx2G","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom"]
```