# Can't access a volume during building a docker image

Tags: docker, build, dockerfile, docker-volume

I am trying to create a docker container with a volume called 'example', which has some files inside it, but I can't access it during build. Here are the files I am using:

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3"
services:
  example:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - "./example:/var/example"
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
```

And:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu
RUN ls /var/example
CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

When I run:

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

It gives me an error:

```
ls: cannot access /var/example: No such file or directory
```

But when I delete the RUN command from the Dockerfile and run `sudo docker-compose up` again, and then run:

```
docker exec -it c949eef14fcd /bin/bash # c949eef14fcd is the id of the created container
ls /var/example
```

... in another terminal window, there is no error, and I can see all the files of the example directory. Why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sorry, I have just found out that volumes are not accessible during build. They are accessible during run of the container, which is said [here in the point 9](https://runnable.com/blog/9-common-dockerfile-mistakes). But when I changed my Dockerfile to this:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:14.04
CMD ["ls", "/var/example"]
```

... it worked perfectly well and printed out all the files inside the example folder.