# Docker-compose - build with maven that re-uses the maven repository

Tags: maven, docker, docker-compose

When building my Spring-boot image using Maven I now do this inside the Dockerfile. Maven will download all dependencies and then compile my files. This takes quite some time.

How can I specify that the build process via docker-compose (Dockerfile) re-uses my "Windows10 Home" Maven repository? So, the number of (new) downloads is minimal. My dev context: I use the Docker quickstart terminal, so using a docker-machine.

The is is a part of my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'
services:
  spring-boot-app:
    image: spring-boot-image
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - mysql-docker-container
    ports:
      - 8087:8080
    volumes:
      - $HOME/.m2/repository:/root/.m2/repository
      - /data/spring-boot-app
```

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM java:8
FROM maven:alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN mvn -v
RUN mvn clean install -DskipTests
EXPOSE 8080
LABEL maintainer=“xyz@holland.nl”
ADD ./target/spring-boot-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /developments/
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/developments/spring-boot-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: None, no error, I see the same list of downloads ... during each build. I would like to reuse the existing Win10/home/repository.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208442/maven-docker-cache-dependencies) question seems to be similar to what you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**@Jack Gore** - thank you very much for pointing me the way. I had seen the post, but there was not a definitive answer yet. After diving in all seperate answers, the info provided me both an answer to the symptom as well with insights how to solve similar questions.

**ANSWER**: Via the Dockerfile you can build the final images via 1 or more subsequent image layers. To prevent the step from re-downloading the dependencies each time, you can make an image layer for the 'downloading the world' of dependencies. Re-downloading will only be done when a dependency changes in the pom.xml file.

To do so, you split the Dockerfile in 2 build steps: first copy the pom.xml file and build it. That will create an image layer with all dependencies. As a second step you build the application.

```
FROM java:8
FROM maven:alpine

# image layer
WORKDIR /app
ADD pom.xml /app
RUN mvn verify clean --fail-never

# Image layer: with the application
COPY . /app
RUN mvn -v
RUN mvn clean install -DskipTests
EXPOSE 8080
ADD ./target/your.jar /developments/
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/developments/your.jar"]
```

Then you get the following build scenario's:

- The **first time** you build this (docker build .)  the dependencies are downloaded and as step 2 the application jar is build.
- When you rebuild immediately the dependencies (pom.xml) and the application sources were not changed. So, the image layers don't need to be changed. The build is ready in no time.
- If you change 1 of your application source files, only a few downloads are downloaded and the application is build. So you are NOT downloading the world.
- If you change the pom.xml file, thus changing the dependencies, then all dependency downloads are done.

The impact of seperating image layers is shown via a [number of very short videos](https://keyholesoftware.com/2015/01/05/caching-for-maven-docker-builds/).

The disadvantage of this way of building is of course that the final (production) image contains more than the appication. Not only the JAR is in it, but also a number of dependencies.

How to solve this iamge being far too big:

- Reduce the image size via a trick. Use the option: --squash. This is explained in [this post](https://medium.com/pismolabs/reducing-image-sizes-and-caching-maven-dependencies-in-docker-builds-b388d3f7aa88).
- Seperate the build process (here: maven and/or ng build --prod) as a step before the docker build step. Then execute the docker build and put ONLY the jar file in final image.
- Use an CI/CD environment with e.g. a Jenkinsfile (pipeline). In the Jenkins pipeline you first build the image. All dependencies are already there. You only rebuild the application. The you perform a docker build, etc.

For my case this is the best option possible. You automate the process AND keep the image size low.

Comment: For the image size, Docker now supports [multistage builds](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/). So basically after you build the jar, you can create a fresh Production image, and copy the jar from the dev image. So your production image doesn't have any of the build/test dependencies in it.