# Automated Spring boot Docker Image failed to build on docker hub when connected to github/bitbucket repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, bitbucket, devops

I have a simple Dockerfile in my spring boot as follow. I am able to build the image successfully locally, and can push using my credentials.

But my build keeps failing on every attempt to build automatically.

> ```
> FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
> LABEL maintainer="xxxxx@xxx.com"
> VOLUME /tmp
> EXPOSE 8080
> ARG JAR_FILE=target/jollof.jar
> ADD ${JAR_FILE} jollof.jar
> ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","- 
> jar","/jollof.jar"]
> ```

From docker hub, I got this from the log.

> ```
> Building in Docker Cloud's infrastructure...
> Cloning into '.'...
> Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx' to 
> the list of known hosts.
> ....
> ....
> Step 6/7 : ADD ${JAR_FILE} jollof.jar
> ADD failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker- 
>   builder674045875/target/jollof.jar: 
> no such file or directory
> ```

Comment: Does this have to do anything with programming? I mean I can't understand.

Comment: @GauravMall yes ... code deployment, or call it devOps.

Comment: Oh yeah, right you are using `BitBucket`. Didn't notice that :)

Answer (score 3):

Unlike your local environment, Docker Hub fetches then builds your project in a fresh environment, so that the file `target/jollof.jar` that is intended to be copied is not available in the docker context. Hence the error you observe.

So I'd suggest refactoring your `Dockerfile` so that `mvn package` or so is done in the `Dockerfile` itself (which is a best practice to adopt, for the sake of reproducibility). Note that this configuration will be working for Docker Hub's automated builds as well as the builds in your local environment.

For example, below is an example `Dockerfile` that inspired by the that of this SO answer [How to convert a Spring-Boot web service into a Docker image?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54299199/9164010) as well as the `Dockerfile` of your post:

```sh
FROM maven:3.6-jdk-8 as maven
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./pom.xml ./pom.xml
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline -B
COPY ./src ./src

# TODO: jollof-* should be replaced with the proper prefix
RUN mvn package && cp target/jollof-*.jar app.jar

# Rely on Docker's multi-stage build to get a smaller image based on JRE
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
LABEL maintainer="xxxxx@xxx.com"
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=maven /app/app.jar ./app.jar

# VOLUME /tmp  # optional
EXPOSE 8080    # also optional

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app/app.jar"]
```

Comment: @ErkMD I completely missed the maven part in building the project, but I thought the idea of docker is to work the same way anywhere ... why did it work on my local environment? does it have access to my local maven installation?

Comment: @IntegralMaster Once built, Docker images indeed ensure portability. But 2 images built from the same `Dockerfile` with different inputs (e.g., 2 different versions of your codebase) will always be different, or even couldn't compile. To sum up, when you do `docker build -t image-name .`, the last argument (here, current folder `.`) denotes what is called Docker's build context (the reference folder from which Docker can retrieve files when you use commands `COPY` or `ADD`). So if you do `ADD target/jollof.jar jollof.jar`, the outcome will be different if `./target/jollof.jar` exists or not.

Comment: I get it now. Basically, I had run 'mvn clean install' before building on my local, and this created a ./target/jollof.jar and this folder was missing on docker hub.