# ./gradlew not found inside docker container

Tags: java, docker, kotlin, gradle

container builds successfully but throws error when starting the stack

```
/bin/sh: 1: ./gradlew: not found
```

here is my Dockerfile :

```
FROM arm32v7/openjdk:7

WORKDIR /iotproject

CMD GRADLE_USER_HOME=cache ./gradlew run
```

dockercompose :

```
version : "3.6"

services:
  server:
    build: ./iotproject
    restart: always
    container_name: server
    volumes:
      - ./volumes/server:/iotproject
```

Things i tried : **setting permissions & owner. still no luck**

Comment: Did you connect to the container's bash and inspected if gradlew is in its expected place?

Comment: Will this help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/61131308/5050667

Comment: @tnte yes i wanted to do that but the container keeps restarting since its failing and as i have set it to restart always, i am unable to pause the container to actually get inside. any workaround for this?

Comment: Maybe make temporary Image without the CMD execution and connect to it for inspection of files. Then you should know if its there or not

Comment: what is the output of `ls ./volumes/server`?