# Docker run command not recognised

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-network

I am trying to run a server and a client in my localhost using java and sockets.
So i created a docker image called *client*

```
FROM java:8
COPY SMTPclient.java /
RUN javac SMTPclient.java
EXPOSE 4000
ENTRYPOINT ["java"]
CMD ["SMTPclient"]
```

And a network called *client_server_network*

```
b503qd6d62f   client_server_network   bridge    local
```

im trying to run the *client image* on that network with the following command

```
docker run --network client_server_network -it client
```

and i am getting the following:

```
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server       to select the "server" VM
    -zero         to select the "zero" VM
    -jamvm        to select the "jamvm" VM
    -dcevm        to select the "dcevm" VM
                  The default VM is server,
                  because you are running on a server-class machine.


    -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
    -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
                  A : separated list of directories, JAR archives,
                  and ZIP archives to search for class files.
    -D<name>=<value>
                  set a system property
    -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
                  enable verbose output
    -version      print product version and exit
    -version:<value>
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  require the specified version to run
    -showversion  print product version and continue
    -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
                  Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
                  in a future release.
                  include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
    -? -help      print this help message
    -X            print help on non-standard options
    -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  enable assertions with specified granularity
    -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
    -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
                  disable assertions with specified granularity
    -esa | -enablesystemassertions
                  enable system assertions
    -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
                  disable system assertions
    -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
                  see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
    -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
                  load native agent library by full pathname
    -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
                  load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
    -splash:<imagepath>
                  show splash screen with specified image
See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html for more details.
```

What is wrong?

Comment: The crux of the issue certainly is related to your `ENTRYPOINT ["java"]` line, which is not standard. To "dockerize" a Java application using a build management system such as Maven, see e.g. [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54299199/9164010), or more generally https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Dockerfile+Java (so I guess your question is a duplicate); also, you might be interested in [docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) to manage the docker networks and so on…