# Docker Build taking more time

Tags: docker, playframework, dockerfile

I have just started using Docker.  Each time, when generating an image, the dependencies are downloaded again.  Hence it is taking more time.  How can I improve the build time on rebuilds?

```sh
FROM openjdk:8
ENV PROJECT_HOME /usr
RUN mkdir -p $PROJECT_HOME/activator $PROJECT_HOME/app
WORKDIR $PROJECT_HOME/activator
RUN wget https://downloads.typesafe.com/typesafe-activator/1.3.2/typesafe-activator-1.3.2.zip && \
    unzip typesafe-activator-1.3.2.zip
ENV PATH $PATH:$PROJECT_HOME/activator/activator-1.3.2
ENV PATH $PATH:$PROJECT_HOME/build/target/universal/stage/bin
COPY . $PROJECT_HOME/app 
WORKDIR $PROJECT_HOME/app
RUN activator clean compile 
EXPOSE 9000 8888
CMD ["activator","run"]
```

Comment: [edit] and add your docker build logs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven docker cache dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208442/maven-docker-cache-dependencies)

Comment: Yeah it does, can volume sharing specified inside docker file ? @GaëlJ